# Get the name of the 2nd non-blank column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  1.0  4.0
2  7.0  1.0  2.0
```

I know I can get, for each row, the name of the first non-blank column with this script:

```
df['first'] = df.dropna(how='all').notna().idxmax(axis=1).astype('string')
```

but how can I get the name of the second non blank column?
This is the expected output:

```
     A    B    C first second
0  1.0  NaN  2.0     A      C
1  NaN  1.0  4.0     B      C
2  7.0  1.0  2.0     A      B
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the NaNs with apply:

```
df[['first', 'second']] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().index), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C first second
0  1.0  NaN  2.0     A      C
1  NaN  1.0  4.0     B      C
2  7.0  1.0  NaN     A      B
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if there are more than 2 non-NaN values per row

Comment: @younggotti if you have an arbitrary number of columns, use `join` instead of named assignment: `df2 = df.join(df.apply(...))`